# How to use shielded audio cable with micro-fit molex connector?

Tags: audio, connector, shielding

This is typical shielded audio cable which I’m supposed to use with micro-fit molex connector. The problem with that cable is that the ground cable/the shield is not insulated and I found it very difficult and messy to crimp it and use it with the micro-fit molex connector. Any ideas how this should be done properly?

By the way, maybe there is a different type of cable which would have 8 wires and would be suitable for everything the power, audio analog and digital signals and would be suitable for use with micro-fit molex connectors, so I don't have to use different types of cables?

Connector:
https://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0430251010_CRIMP_HOUSINGS.xml

Audio cable:
http://www.tasker.it/en/p/1625/c121?f=18

[image: shielded audio cable]

Comment: Links to the connector and cable please.

Comment: @Andyaka Connector:
https://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0430251010_CRIMP_HOUSINGS.xml
Audio cable:
http://www.tasker.it/en/p/1625/c121?f=18
Same connector will be used for digital signals and power

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to solder a more manageable size wire to the shield.  Then cover all the messy bare wire, including the solder join, with heat-shrink tubing.